# The code is generating only last part of string? Can anyone help to fix this

Tags: python

```
def pig_latin(text):  
    say = "ay"
    
    words = text.split()
    print(words)
    
    for word in words:
        x = word[1:] + word[:1] + say
        y = ("".join(x))
    return y
print(pig_latin("hello how are you"))
```

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: # "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
It should at add first char to the end of the word + ay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep overwriting `y` in the loop, you need to save every part, a first solution would be `y += "".join(x)` but that would give `ellohayowhayreaayouyay`

So use a list to keep every modified word, so you can then but a space between them. Also a string slice is a string, you don't need `"".join`

```
def pig_latin(text):
    say = "ay"
    y = []
    for word in text.split():
        x = word[1:] + word[:1] + say
        y.append(x)
    return " ".join(y)


print(pig_latin("hello how are you"))  # ellohay owhay reaay ouyay
```

---

Shortened version

```
def pig_latin(text, say="ay"):
    return " ".join(word[1:] + word[:1] + say for word in text.split())
```